# Pixelized Circle in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to generate something like this in TikZ:

[image: Pixelated Minecraft Circle]

Which can be generated for an arbitrary radius [here](https://donatstudios.com/PixelCircleGenerator), which uses [this code](https://github.com/donatj/Circle-Generator/blob/master/generator.js).

I know how to do it manually in TikZ but it is a real pain. Since I saw in the manual that there is a way to do a for loop in TikZ, there must be a way to generate the pixelated(/minecraft) circle.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A very quick proposal.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[gray](-5,-5) grid[step=0.25] (5,5);
 \foreach \X in {-4.875,-4.625,...,4.875}
 {\foreach \Y in {-4.875,-4.625,...,4.875}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sqrt(abs(\X*\X+\Y*\Y-4*4))}
 \ifnum\itest=0
 \draw[gray,fill=red] (\X-0.125,\Y-0.125) rectangle (\X+0.125,\Y+0.125);
 \fi}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And something in which you can adjust the parameters. The `fudge` factor determines the "width" of the circle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={radius=4.8;xmax=5;xstep=0.25;fudge=0.9;}]
 \draw[gray](-xmax,-xmax) grid[step=xstep] (xmax,xmax);
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{xmax-xstep/2}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xnext}{xmax-3*xstep/2}
 \foreach \X in {-\Xmax,-\Xnext,...,\Xmax}
 {\foreach \Y in {-\Xmax,-\Xnext,...,\Xmax}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{fudge*sqrt(abs(\X*\X+\Y*\Y-radius*radius))}
 \ifnum\itest=0
 \draw[gray,fill=red] (\X-xstep/2,\Y-xstep/2) rectangle (\X+xstep/2,\Y+xstep/2);
 \fi}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And this is an attempt of the implementation of the prescription from the [web site pointed out by tch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare
function={radius=4.8;xmax=5;xstep=0.25;},pixel at/.style n
args={2}{insert path={({#1*xstep},{#2*xstep}) rectangle
++(xstep,xstep)}}]
 \draw[gray](-xmax,-xmax) grid[step=xstep] (xmax,xmax);
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Ymax}{int(cos(45)*radius/xstep)}
 \foreach \Z in {0,90,180,270}
 {\foreach \Y in {-\Ymax,...,\the\numexpr\Ymax+1\relax}
 {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myx}{sqrt(radius*radius-\Y*\Y*xstep*xstep)/xstep}
 \draw[rotate around={\Z:(0,0)},gray,fill=red,pixel at={\myx}{\Y}];}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It might be worth nothing that this approach is a bit different than the classic [circle drawing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) in that there are some squares which share faces.

Comment: @tch Yes, that's a good point, thanks! I tried to use their prescription but I am not convinced I did it right (at the ends of the octants it doesn't look good).

Comment: Looks really good, thanks a lot! For my purposes, it's perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for bumping this post, but I recently stumbled upon this thread and found the discussion extremely relevant to a project I'm currently working on using TikZ. The challenge of creating a pixelated Minecraft circle in TikZ, as you've been discussing, is quite fascinating and aligns closely with my interests.

To add to the previous conversations, I'd like to share some insights and a potential approach. As many of you have pointed out, manually generating these circles in TikZ can be quite tedious. However, the use of loops in TikZ, as demonstrated in the earlier replies, offers a more efficient way to tackle this challenge.

Drawing inspiration from the [circle generator minecraft](https://minecraftcirclegenerate.com/), I believe we can enhance the TikZ method to achieve a similar effect. This website is quite handy for generating circles of any arbitrary radius, offering a clear visual template for pixelated circles.

Based on this, here's my proposed modification to the TikZ code, aiming to replicate the effect seen on the Minecraft Circle Generator:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={radius=4.5; xstep=0.25;}]
 \draw[gray](-5,-5) grid[step=xstep] (5,5);
 \foreach \X in {-5,-4.75,...,5}
  {\foreach \Y in {-5,-4.75,...,5}
   {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{sqrt(abs(\X*\X+\Y*\Y-radius*radius))}
    \ifnum\itest=0
     \draw[gray,fill=blue] (\X-xstep/2,\Y-xstep/2) rectangle (\X+xstep/2,\Y+xstep/2);
    \fi
   }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this code, the radius and xstep are adjustable parameters that control the circle's size and the pixel size, respectively. The loop iterates over a grid, and the condition within it checks whether a point is on the circumference of the circle, using the Pythagorean theorem. If so, that grid square is filled.

This method should allow for creating pixelated circles similar to those from the Minecraft Circle Generator, but with the flexibility and control offered by TikZ.

I'm eager to hear any thoughts, feedback, or further enhancements you might suggest!

Best regards

kiwn